# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).leanModal is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, materialize

I'm using Materialize css library and laravel to create a Survey application:
here is my html code:

```
<div id="doDelete" class="modal bottom-sheet">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <h4>Are you sure?</h4>
              <p>Do you wish to delete this survey called "{{ $survey->title }}"?</p>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="/survey/{{ $survey->id }}/delete" class=" modal-action waves-effect waves-light btn-flat red-text">Yep yep!</a>
                <a class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-light green white-text btn">No, stop!</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and init.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible({
    accordion: false
  });

 $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();

  $(document).on('click', '.delete-option', function() {
    $(this).parent(".input-field").remove();
  });
```

but I have this error when trying to execute delete function

```
init.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).leanModal is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (init.js:6)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.min.js:2)
```

also I include  init.js and jquery.min.js

```
 <script src="{{ URL::asset('jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    {!! MaterializeCSS::include_js() !!}
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('init.js') }}"></script>
```

any help please !! thanks.

Comment: I don't see a `.modal-trigger` element in the HTML; is that in the code elsewhere?

Comment: You aren't including a file for leanModal plugin

Comment: <a href="#doDelete" style="float:right;" class="modal-trigger red-text">Delete Survey</a>

Comment: @mark.hch ,yes i include it like above

Comment: I see it in your JavaScript above, but not in the HTML. If there's no HTML element with a class of `modal-trigger`, then you are calling `.leanModal()` on an empty jQuery object. The `is not a function` error you're getting, as @charlietfl pointed out, seems like you're not including the `leanModal` plugin. If you don't have the file local, you could use a CDN: `<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.leanmodal/1.1/jquery.leanmodal.min.js'></script>`

Comment: yes,thank you I miss the  jquery.leanmodal script but i have another issue the modal is shown but not working

Answer (score 0):

```
               <section class="new">
                    <center><h2 class="text center">RECENT-PROJECT</h2></center>
                    <div id="carousel">
                            <img src="carousel 11.jpg" id="item-11"/>
                            <img src=" carousel image4.jpg" id="item-4"/>
                            <img src="image8.jpg" id="item-8"/>
                            <img src="image9.jpg" id="item-9"/>
                             <img src="image13.jpg" id="item-13"/>
                             <img src="image15.jpg" id="item-15"/>
                             <img src="images 12.jpg" id="item-12"/>
                             <img src="images 14.jpg" id="item-14"/>
                             <img src="image16.jpg" id="item-9"/>
                        </div>

                        <script>
                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                  var carousel = $("#carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
                                    flankingItems: 3,
                                  });

                                  $('#prev').bind('click', function () {
                                    carousel.prev();
                                    return false
                                  });

                                  $('#next').bind('click', function () {
                                    carousel.next();
                                    return false;
                                  });
                                });
                            </script>
                    </section>
```